# JQuery Evaluating Empty Val() Weirdly

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden div that contains a "ChildBirthdate" text input.  There is a button that the user can click named "Add Child" which unhides the hidden div.
What's odd is when I loop through the birthdate fields and check if the val is empty, the ChildBirthDate value is not empty. Here is the html:

```
                <div class="ChildData">

                    <div class="form-group required Child">
                        <label for="ChildBirthDate" class="col-md-4 control-label">Child/Dependent Birth Date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" name="ChildBirthDate" class="form-control BirthDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" value="" />
                            <span class="help-block">
                                Please enter your Birth Date
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="RemoveChild" style="margin-left:-25px; margin-top:5px; display:block" href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                Remove Child
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    $('.BirthDate').each(function () {
    /*
    if ($(this).val() != '' && !isValidDate()) {
        datesAreValid = false;
        return;
    }
    */
    alert($(this).prop('id'));
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        alert($(this).val()); // alerts on hidden childbirthdate even though value=""
        alert($(this).prop('id')); // alert empty on childbirthdate.  Others alert the id (PrimaryBirthdate, SpouseBirthdate)
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not alerting the value, it's alerting the (non-existant) ID. Comment out `alert($(this).prop('id'))` and you'll see no alert appears.

Comment: please share jsfiddle for the same, It may be possible form-control class is fiddeling something here

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xhjhck5d/

Comment: Instead of `$(this).val()`, you can write `this.value`. Instead of `$(this).prop('id')`, you can write `this.id`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Your response has no relevance to this question. Also, this is tagged jQuery, not JavaScript.

Comment: @AaronEveleth, thank you for your little observations. SO allows us to post Comments and Answers. Mine is a comment, not an answer. And POJS efficiencies, when available, should be encouraged.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Your last point is a fair one. But the OP could be mislead to think your answer had some relevance to his issue, which it does not.

Comment: @AaronEveleth, indeed he could. Hopefully you have done enough to help him avoid that possibility. Thank you.